# Show Magento attribute as a selectable option on frontend

Tags: magento, attributes, product

In my Magento shop I want customers to select the size of the product which they wish to order.
I've created a custom attribute `ringsize` with options ranging from 15 to 22.
I see the attribute dropdown appear in the backend when adding a new product, however, I don't select a value here, since that is up to the visitor on the frontend.

Now, when I visit my product detail page on the frontend I don't see a dropdown where a visitor can select the site of the product. How do I enable that? Should it be done in the template or is this something Magento would provide out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do this with Attributes (at least out of the box). You need to use either Configurable product functionality or Custom options ([here is the info on how to create them](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/create-custom-variants-and-options-of-a-product)).

[Here is the info about their differences](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/difference-between-custom-variants-options-and-configurable-product-type):

*Use custom options if:*

- You have a small catalog and are looking for a quick way to create
  customizable products.
- You don't need to manage inventory.
- You have a    small catalog and want an easy way to offer product
  variations.
- The    options are applied after the product is ordered, such as
  custom    embroidery on a tee shirt.

*Use a configurable product options if:*

- You manage a large catalog of products with many variations.
- You want to manage inventory separately for each variation.
- You want each variation to have its own product page.

Comment: Wow thanks! It seems I need custom options in this case, but I'm not sure. Could you advise?
My case (based on the custom options situation you describe)
1. Correct. I sell rings. My total catalog consists of about 17 different rings. Rings come in sizes 15 to 22. Preferably: not all rings are available in all sizes.
2. I do have a physical inventory of the rings, meaning at some time they will run out and I will need to re-order at the manufacturer.
3. Correct. 
4. What does that mean? After the product is ordered? I would imagine ringsize is something that is indicated when ordering?

Comment: 2. It looks like you need to work with Configurable products, or you should manually delete an option that will run out of stock. 4. It means that it's not a real product (as with Configurable products), so it's just an attribute for you as administrator.

Comment: Ok, configurable products it is then. Do you know of a tutorial how I can configure that each ring comes in a very specific set of sizes (so not all rings are available in all sizes)? I'm assuming the ringsize will be a custom product attribute, but should it be configured as a dropdown in the backend? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Configurable product is a collection of simple products, i.e. Golden Ring Size 17 would be a simple product, Goldern Ring Size 18, Goldern Ring Size 19, Goldern Ring Size 20 would also be separate simple products. Then you will create configurable product Golden Ring and will assign all of simple products to it like these shoes in official Demo http://demo.magentocommerce.com/asicsr-men-s-gel-kayanor-xii-94.html

Comment: Here is a guide http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a configurable product for that. First, create two simple products with the ringsize attribute set to 15 and 22 respectively. Then create a configurable product with ringsize as a configurable attribute and specify the two simple products as configurable associated products.

Comment: you can read more about configurable products here http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-configurable-product-type-part-1/

Comment: Thanks. I just went for simple products since I found out earlier that I can't set the inventory quantity on configurable products, only on simple products (http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/226539/).  Will I run into that same issue when following your suggestion?

Comment: The inventory quantity can be set to the simple products that make up the configurable that is basically a shell product. If that is still an issue, you can use one simple product and set up a required custom option "ringsize" with two values to select from. The customer then must specify that option before adding a product to cart